# delete subfolders and files without deleting parent folder and child folder?

Tags: windows, rm

For this type of `dir` structure :

```
\\rdwlhsdevserver\root\user1\folders\testdat.txt
\\rdwlhsdevserver\root\abhay\testdat.txt
\\rdwlhsdevserver\root\testuser\folders1\folder2\testdat.txt
\\rdwlhsdevserver\root\devadmin\input\testdat.txt
\\rdwlhsdevserver\root\admin\testdata\testdat.txt
```

I know that I can use `rm -rf <<folderPath>>` to delete parent folder and all sub-folders, but I want to delete all folders and files except `\\\rdwlhsdevserver\root\Childfolder`

After running `cmd`, output should be like:

```
\\rdwlhsdevserver\root\user1\
\\rdwlhsdevserver\root\abhay\
\\rdwlhsdevserver\root\testuser\
\\rdwlhsdevserver\root\devadmin\
\\rdwlhsdevserver\root\admin\
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
rm -rf /path/to/root/*/*
```

NOTE: Please test this first by making a similar test directory structure. Your shell may not support this kind of syntax (I tested on bash and zsh).

Comment: In `bash`, that `**` is the same as `*` unless you turn on the `globstar` option to enable zsh-style recursive globbing. But anyway, here, you'd want `*/*`, not `**/*`. You'd also need to tell the shell to remove hidden files (add `(D)` in `zsh` or turn on the `dotglob` option in `bash`).

Comment: Good points. And with globstar on, bash will actually delete the children of root with `**/*`. zsh will do the same. I am going to update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

With GNU or BSD `find`:

```
find /path/to/root -mindepth 2 -delete
```

With `zsh`:

```
rm -rf /path/to/root/*/*(D)
```

However note that if there are symlinks to directories in `/path/to/root`, they will be followed to remove the files in them. You may also run into a `Arg list too big` error which you could work around by enabling the `rm` builtin:

```
zmodload zsh/files
rm -rf /path/to/root/*/.(D)
```

(the builtin version of `rm` can remove `.`)

If you don't want to follow symlinks:

```
zmodload zsh/files
dirs=(/path/to/root/*(D/)) && rm -rf $^dirs/.
```